# Links to files are not configured properly

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

When I was developing website on my computer everything was fine because drupal was installed in virtual host's root directory. But when I moved website to another server to one of www's subdirectory, links to files were broken. Urls look like "/sites/default/files/..." and they point to the www root. I've already added `RewriteBase /my_dir` to .htaccess file but it's still not working.

**UPDATE:**
Mistake was actually obvious: urls were absolute, with "/" in the beginning of it. Thanks to you guys anyway.

**UPDATE 1:**
And yet it's not that obvious. I use pathauto module and when the page is accessed through this "/content/page-title", so when I use relative path to files it doesn't work neither.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you might be make it right by changing the path from `/sites/default/files/` to `file_directory_path()` .Some of these below functions may prove useful to you

`base_url`-Returns the base URL of the Drupal installation

`file_directory_path()` - Returns a string containing the path to Drupal's 'files' directory.

`path_to_theme()` - Returns the path to the current themed element.

Comment: So if I'm working with body field of the node, I need to use PHP filter to paste an image? Doesn't look like the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

So your Drupal website runs under a subdirectory? (for example `http://www.yourwebsite.com/my_dir`)

What you could do is to uncomment and change the `$base_url` variable inside `settings.php` to the correct URL. (line 289). Drupal will generate the correct URL for all your assets (css, js, images, ...) and no PHP filter is required.

```php
$base_url = 'http://www.yourwebsite.com/my_dir'; // NO trailing slash!
```

Comment: I've added this thing to settings.php file but links to files from content still don't work.

Comment: So URL to assets (CSS, JS) are now correct? When you say 'links to files from content', do you mean the url to images set using the TinyMCE or FCKEditor?

Comment: urls to assets like css and js were always correct. I mean images and other files in body field. I don't use wysiwyg editors, just html.

Comment: Oh ok misunderstood the problem. So all URL's used within the body field are not correct? You can use the 'Pathologic' module which adds a filter processing on fields and correct faulty URL's. You can use for exameple the 'Full URL' option.